# When to use explicit specifier for multi-argument constructors?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, explicit, multiple-arguments

I have recently learned about the `explicit` specifier.

Suppose we have:

```
f( W, W, W );
```

Now if we do

```
f( 42, 3.14, "seven" );
```

The compiler will attempt the following implicit conversions:

```
f( W(42), W(3.14), W("seven") );
```

If we have defined matching constructors for W, namely:

```
W(int);
W(double);
W(std::string);
```

...it will succeed.

However, if we make the first one explicit:

```
explicit W(int);
```

... this disables the implicit conversion.

You would now have to write:

```
f( W(42), 3.14, "seven" );
```

i.e. it is forcing you to explicitly state the conversion

**Now on to the question:**

It is possible to write:

```
explicit W(int,int); // 2 arguments!
```

This compiles!

But I can't see any corresponding scenario that might require this syntax.

Can anyone provide a minimal example?

Comment: Part of this might be just for the sake of consistency, since multi-parameter functions may also have defaults, e.g. `explicit W(int,int=0);`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your constructor is explicit and the class doesn't supply a non-explicit constructor taking `initializer_list<T>`, then you cannot copy-list-initialize an instance.

```
W w = {1,2}; // compiles without explicit, but not with
```

[Simple live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d973bedc26ba3942)

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
   explicit A(int, int) {}
};

class B
{
public:
    B(int, int) {}
};

int main()
{
   B b = {1,2};
   A a = {1,2};
}
```

Quotes from standard:

8.5/16

> — If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) braced-init-list, the
>   object or reference is list-initialized (8.5.4).

8.5.4/3

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as
>   follows: ...
>
> Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered. The
>   applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen
>   through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7). If a narrowing
>   conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments,
>   the program is ill-formed.

Comment: Re-phrasing my previous comment: maybe the mention of `initializer_list` makes the answer confusing. But I think it is correct.

Comment: When you say "implicit constructor", you mean "constructor not declared with the `explicit` keyword", and that does make sense, but when I read it, I think of implicitly generated constructors that are not declared by the user. (In your example, `A`'s copy constructor, for instance.) I don't know if "implicit constructor" is a generally accepted term the way you're using it, but it's not one I've come across before.